# Under what conditions can I access the HTML-DOM of a child IFrame from the hosting website?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, iframe, cross-domain

What can cause my website to not have access to a child IFrame's DOM via Javascript? Are there cross-domain restrictions in place? Does HTTPS play a role?

Comment: different browsers/versions do different things. Previous versions of Safari have allowed me to gain access where the domains didn't match. Newer versions, along with Firefox, don't allow it and throw exceptions. I think you still may be able to as long as your iframe and page are within the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access iframes if they are coming from the same domain. If you are hosting www.mysite.com and the iframe inserted is from www.yahoo.com you cannot access it. Trying to do that will get an access denied javascript error. This is one of the checks to avoid cross site scripting I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it across domains, and this extends to subdomains as well as across SSL. The child however can access the parent.